# p0104 MAF sensor

Tags: ford, focus, maf, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

I'm having a P0104 error code, but there's no MAF sensor in my car (Focus mk2). There is a MAP sensor in it, but that should have another error code.

Any idea how this is possible ?

Comment: Which engine do you have and have you tried using another scanner?

Comment: It's a 2010 Ford Focus Mk2 1.4 gas European model

I'm using a 20$ aftermarket scanner, with free software, but I would think it can at least read a trouble code. Do you think it can misread ?

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with your engine. It’s possible that it’s a calculated PID. It’s also possible that your software is giving a false reading. Can you provide detailed pictures of the intake tract  on your engine?

Comment: It's getting dark here, but I have this 2 from the internet:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9pgd_CznHM
http://www.talkford.com/community/uploads/monthly_09_2013/post-83112-0-90256400-1378289204.jpg

Both 1.6 engines, but they look identical to my 1.4

Does this work ?

Comment: No sensor around the air filter, but I can locate the MAP sensor at the end of the intake pipe close to the engine

Answer (score -1):

Your vehicle has a MAF sensor. Most modern vehicles with fuel injection do. The location of the MAP sensor is the intake manifold whereas the MAF sensor is usually located just before the air filter assembly. They measure 2 different parameters.

The Manifold Absolute Pressure (MAP) sensor is used by the Powertrain Control Module (PCM) for engine load input. The PCM uses this input, as well as others, to calculate the correct amount of fuel to inject into the cylinders. The MAP sensor measures the absolute pressure inside the intake manifold of the engine

A mass (air) flow sensor (MAF) is used to find out the mass flow rate of air entering a fuel-injected internal combustion engine. If I remember correctly this sensor is a hot platinum wire sensor with a thermistor to measure the heat of the element. As the air goes by it it cools the element and the amount of current  required to maintain the temperature is proportional to the amount of air flow.

The element in the MAF sensor is probably dirty and needs to be cleaned using a sensor cleaner or disc brake cleaner which leaves no residue.

Here is a guy cleaning the MAF sensor on a 2012 ford focus

https://youtu.be/WVj7fDkfrZQ

Comment: I can tell with 100% certainty there's no MAF sensor. 

It's a similar engine to what I found at this forum: 

http://www.talkford.com/community/topic/219395-where-is-the-maf-sensor/

Comment: In the video it is the new model (Mk3) from 2012, with the MAF sensor clearly visible. 

Mine is 2005-2011 (Mk2). See pic at below link.

http://www.talkford.com/community/uploads/monthly_09_2013/post-83112-0-90256400-1378289204.jpg

Trust me, no MAF sensor in it. Any idea ?

Comment: The automakers have been using MAF sensors since the late 1980's in varying configurations. The MAF sensor in the video is visible after the guy did a bit of disassembly first. Your car is 2010 and should be in the same location.

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one having this issue, found another forum entry:

Comment: http://www.fordownersclub.com/forums/topic/30416-maf-sensor-location/

Comment: The guy commented he solved it by replacing the MAP; still find the wrong OBD code strange